# data version dosen't increase when we delete or add an child entity in spring data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `@version` annotation in spring data so I have a parent entity, and it has list of child entity. when I delete an element from child list the parent version doesn't increase. can anyone clarify for me this `@version` alternative,

why the versing in this case doesn't increase, is it a good way to manage versioning or should I use trasaction "lock".

in the documentation i read that the version update only on updating a row
in the databse but in my case i put version on parent entity and i want

note: i searched a lot in the internet but i didnt find a clear solution, can any one help me.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: please see the answer  i will explain with example.

Comment: You could also update your question, that might be clearer for people trying to help :)

Comment: You might want to give feedback to A. Ebrahim, if his answers helps (upvote), solved the issue (upvote and accept) or neither: comment why not.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Hibernate. Lets say that the "UnderlyingPerTradingAccount" table has a column called "trading_account_id", which is a foreign key to the TradingAccount table. In order to achieve the behavior you described, you need to change the mapping. Can you try this:

```
public class TradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name="trading_account_id", referencedColumnName = "trading_account_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private List<UnderlyingPerTradingAccount> underlyingPerTradingAccounts;

  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```

and

```
public class UnderlyingPerTradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="trading_account_id", nullable = false)
  private TradingAccount tradingAccount;
  private Boolean enableBuy;
  private Boolean enableSell;
}
```

This should mark the parent entity as "dirty" when the child entity is updated and trigger the version increment.

However, I would think of some other method to track "version" changes of the parent entity as this would just cause an additional overhead and update statements to the parent.

Comment: just edited the answer because of a typo in the code